# Question about implicit (?) data conversion of cv::Vec3f to cv::Scalar during Mat initialization

Tags: c++, opencv

Let's say we have this simple Mat

```
cv::Mat_<cv::Vec3f> image;

image.create(100,200);
image = cv::Vec3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
```

My question would be why does this work properly by initializing the whole Mat?

If I had to guess, the following method is called (operator=):
https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#aa5c947f7e449a4d856a4f3a87fcebd50

which only accepts a Scalar.

So I tried to search it out a bit more and I found out there could be the possibility of the Vec3f being data converted *implicitly* to a Scalar.

Also, I found this piece of code, which I am not entirely sure if it is contained within OpenCV:

```
static explicit operator Scalar (
    Vec3b v
)
```

But: To the best of my knowledge, this only helps when you try to convert data types *explicitly* with something like:

```
Scalar s = (Scalar)point // where point is a cv::Vec3f
```

So what does actually happen in the initial initialization code? Does the Vec3f have to be data converted to the Scalar as I assumed? And if so, how exactly is it accomplished behind the scenes so that it actually works?

Comment: You are looking at a reference for a class named `Mat`, but you are actually using a class template named `Mat_`. How, if at all, are the two related?

Comment: [Right here](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/df/dfc/classcv_1_1Mat__.html#a58f65e6db94e9c92d58ff3ae523ae340). `Mat_<T>` has an assignment operator taking `T`

Comment: So was it that simple? I thought they had (almost) the same methods... Here is somehow described simply in what they are different: https://itom.bitbucket.io/latest/docs/07_plugins/development/openCVMat.html